# Ansible stdout as blockinfile marker

Tags: ansible

I have the below `blockinfile` task (mentioned at the end) which is writing content of some command outputs from `R_vlan_list` register variable.  I am writing the `stdout_lines[0]` output as marker which is like this:

> Net::Route Domain: RD2001

Is it possible to write just the last word "RD2001" instead of full output as marker?

In summary I want the output like below:

```
###### RD2001 ######
net vlan VLAN2001
```

Instead of below

```
###### Net::Route Domain: RD2001 ######
net vlan VLAN2001
```

This is the current task in my playbook

```yaml
- name: Logging Output-Vlans-Route_Domains
  blockinfile:
      marker: "###### {{ item.stdout_lines[0] | join('\n') }} ######"
      content: "{{ logging_content }}"
      dest: "{{ Helper_Test }}"
  with_items:
        - "{{ R_vlan_list.results }}"
```

Comment: Anybody help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the component you want from the line. I'm a little confused about why you're passing `item.stdout_lines[0]` to `join('\n')`, because it doesn't seem like you would want newlines in your marker, so I'm going to ignore that.

Assuming that `item.stdout_lines[0]` contains `Net::Route Domain: RD2001`, you could write:

```
- name: Logging Output-Vlans-Route_Domains
  blockinfile:
      marker: "###### {{ item.stdout_lines[0].split()[-1]  }} ######"
      content: "{{ logging_content }}"
      dest: "{{ Helper_Test }}"
  with_items:
        - "{{ R_vlan_list.results }}"
```

This splits your string on whitespace, which would result in the list
`['Net::Route', 'Domain:', 'RD2001']`, and then takes the last element
of that list (which is `RD2001`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes join('\n') is not required and I removed it. But I am getting below error when I use Split:                                                                                                                            **** The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'split' *****